# Rasa ask for new entity but keeping previous intent

Tags: python, android-intent, entity, rasa

I have an intent rent example:
Me: I want to rent a house in Madrid with 2 bedrooms
Bot: Which type? House, duplex...
Me: Duplex
Bot: You want a house in Madrid with 2 bedrooms, there are some examples
Me: And with 3 bedrooms?
Bot: You want a house in Madrid with 3 bedrooms, there are some examples
How I implement the last part? How I can keep the context of the last intent and answer with the new entity provided by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is using rasa interactive and add them manually. With the intent inform